# Query on at least and not present in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries:

1. Query the id number of the students who at least enrolled subj1 and subj2 courses (I do not know how to code for at least)
2. Query the id number, name, and age of the students who did not enroll subj2 course.

I coded something as below - which returns an empty table even though I should get some values.

```
Select sno, sname, age 
from student
where not exists (select cno from course where cno ='C2');
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: You probably are missing a table. Because you have `students` and `courses`, but not `student_courses`. But without some sample data we dont know how to solve this

Comment: Your subquery isn't _correlated_ with the outer query. If there are _any_ rows in `course` where `cno = 'C2'` then no rows should be returned from the outer query. OTOH, if no `'C2'` courses exist then _all_ rows in `student` would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a table connecting students with courses in a many-to-many, so that each student can enroll in more than one course and each course can contain multiple students.

So for the sake of this example, let's call it StudentsToCourses.
This table should contain the student id and the course id, and it's primary key should contain the combination of both it's columns.

So the first query would be something like (to get student numbers enrolled into at least one of the two courses):

```
SELECT sno
FROM StudentToCourses 
WHERE cno IN ('C1', 'C2')
```

or this (to get students enrolled into both courses):

```
SELECT sno
FROM StudentToCourses 
WHERE cno IN ('C1', 'C2')
GROUP BY sno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cno) = 2
```

Note that the subquery in the `EXISTS` operator is correlated to the main query using the student number.

The second query is almost the same as the first one, except instead of `IN` you use `=`, and instead of `EXISTS` you use `NOT EXISTS`.
Since this seems like a homework question, I'll leave it up to you to write the code, otherwise you will not learn anything from this.

Comment: It isn't clear whether the OP's "at least enrolled subj1 and subj2 courses" means `and` or `or`. Your answer addresses `or`.